# How to set the initial tab from outside

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

Consider the scenes below:

```
<Scene key='home' component={HomeComponent} hideNavBar title={'home'}/>
<Scene key="myTabBar" tabs={true} hideNavBar tabBarStyle={style.tabBarStyle}>
    <Scene 
        key="myTab" 
        title="My Tab" 
        icon={MyTabIcon} 
        component={MyTabComponent} hideNavBar />
    <Scene 
        key="myTab_1" 
        title="My Tab 1" 
        icon={MyTabIcon} 
        component={MyTabComponent1} hideNavBar />
</Scene>
```

I have two buttons in HomeComponent, Button1 and button Button2.

I want to show `myTab_1` when Button1 clicked, and show myTab_2 when Button2 clicked.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: How do you give more detail about?

Answer (score 0):

Actually its quite simple, but there is no documentation or issue discussed. To evaluate this, we can look at the [source code of TabBar](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/src/TabBar.js) in repo src directory.

```
... (imports)

class TabBar extends Component {

  ...

  static onSelect(el) {
    if (!Actions[el.props.name]) {
      throw new Error(
        `No action is defined for name=${el.props.name} ` +
        `actions: ${JSON.stringify(Object.keys(Actions))}`);
    }
    if (typeof el.props.onPress === 'function') {
      el.props.onPress();
    } else {
      Actions[el.props.name]();
    }
  }
}
```

When we click on the tab itself, we actually invoke the function `onSelect` (take a look at render part) which simply routes using `Action[tabbarbutton.props.name]()`

For your code its `Action.myTab_1()` in your TouchableOpacity.

Comment: Sorry for late in reply. I tried it before but its not working.

Comment: Then your Scene tree should be wrong. Can you edit and show me your router tree